# React ref a nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I ran into an issue which I do not know how to "properly" solve.

I have two components, let's call them `parent` and `child`.
`child` component is "generated" by a call to a function that creates it, let's call this function `child creator`.
`parent` component has a button which shows/hides the `child` but is also suppose to `.focus()` the HTML dom node which is what the child is. Now the show/hide I implemented via the state, but I do not know how to  apply javascript's `.focus()` onto the child's HTML dom node.

There is also a small catch... the `child` component is being "generated" and "returned" by a call to a plain old javascript function, let's call it `createChild`.

This is due to the fact that child component needs to be vastly different based on what the parameters that were passed are, however, it also needs to be reused throughout the application so the `createChild` functions make sure that all the `child` components are the same, given the same inputs.

I tried passing `ref` to the creator, however since `ref` is not a prop, it is not accessible. What is the proper way to "grab" the children's dom nodes in order to `.focus()` them when the button is clicked since I cannot pass a `ref`?

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lyj6x2948m

Comment: could you maybe provide some code in codesandbox or some similar service?

Comment: You can pass `ref` as a prop. Have you tried it?

Comment: @devserkan You cannot since the creator is a regular fucntions, React doesnt allow it

Comment: @LazarNikolic  https://codesandbox.io/s/lyj6x2948m

Comment: edit your question to include codesandbox

Comment: @ArthurCantarela not sure if this is what you meant, I do not know how to "import it here" if it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for everyone wondering, I found a solution to the problem.
To begin with, the issue was not in the `ref` passing (at least not explicitly), but rather in a way controls are being created (which doesnt allow the ref to be passed).

The `controlCreator` function is a good old simple javascript function, and it was being used to provide a type for a `React.createElement` because the result of calling the `controlCreator` ends up being a react component.
I have however came to an understanding of why this is wrong and have instead proceeded to generate my `child` elements by the `controlCreator` and then using `React.cloneElement` to inject them with a `ref`. This way, the element is being cloned within a parent and can thus be referenced by parent's methods.

[A link to a working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/38p9v841n5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, child ref is accessible since it is part of real DOM. I made a simple example with two nested components, check it out:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  focusRef(ref) {
    ref.focus();
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Child focusRef={this.focusRef} />
  }
};

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button 
        ref={childRef => this.childRef = childRef}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.props.focusRef(this.childRef)}
      >
        When mouse enters, i get focused
      </button>
    );
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
*:focus {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Also, I strongly recommend further reading on [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

Comment: I mean there are monumental differences between your example and what I described, for one, you are reacting to an event fired from a child, obviously, you can reference the child from within itself and only pass it back to the parent for what the parent wants to do with it. This example doesn't really illustrate the problem at all, neither of them. The event-trigger needs to happen on a parent element, and child has to be focused, and since `focus` is not a property it kind-of is not passable, to my knowledge, check the codesandbox link i made.

Comment: Secondly you are instantiating a child as a class, where as I am using a plain old javascript function to generate a react component and return it as a child, which could pass the `ref` as a prop, if that was to be done by react, but its not. If you have a better solution im open to suggestions

Comment: I've misunderstood your question and I'm sorry for that. Working on improved solution =)